# CSS: Background-image fails to load properly when using flexbox

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, background-image

I"m trying to use flexbox to make a "sticky" footer, and it works fine on other pages, but on the page that has a form, the background image fails to load.

This problem only appears when using flexbox. Without it, everything loads as normal. I've tried using browser prefixes.

When the page loads, it loads without the background image, but as soon as I click inside a form field or hover over a “a:hover” link, the background image appears. If you click Submit, the image disappears again until you click inside a form field or hover over a link.

After making the image appear with a click or a hover, then disappear again with the Submit button, then reappear with a click or hover, it does not disappear again, which makes me wonder if it’s related to the action attribute in the form tag, which right now is not there (but this disappearing image problem stays the same with # placeholder for the action attribute). I don’t currently have a server address to send form data to, so I don’t really know how to test that hypothesis.

HTML and CSS below.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="not-footer">
    <header>
        <div>
            <h1>Name Namerson</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">About</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <section>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <form>
                <label>
                    Name
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Smith">
                </label>
                <label>
                    Email
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                </label>
                <label>
                    Message
                    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                </label>
                <button name="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </section>

        <aside>
            <h3>Connect with Me</h3>
            <div>
                <a href="https://github.com">
                    <img src="assets/images/github_icon.png" alt="github link"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
                    <img src="assets/images/linkedin_icon.png" alt="linked in link"></a>
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
                    <img src="assets/images/stackoverflow_icon.png" alt="stack overflow link"></a>
            </div>    
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="flex-footer>
    &#9400;Copyright 2018 Name Namerson
</footer>
```

CSS (the flex styling is at the top: the rest is included just in case...):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('../images/circles-and-roundabouts.png');
    color: #777777;
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* flex styling */
.not-footer {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.flex-footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* header styling */
header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header div {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

/* main content styling */
.main {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

section {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 30px 32px 30px 0;
}

/* contact.html styling */
section form {
    padding: 30px;
}

input, textarea {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
    margin: 8px 0 16px 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
    height: 200px;
}

form button {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* aside styling */
aside {
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

aside div {
    width: 202px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
}

aside a:hover,
.box a:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

/* footer styling */
footer {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 5px solid #4aaaa5;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .75em;
}

/* nav syling */
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777777;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #474747;
}

nav a {
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 0 16px 0 10px;
}

nav a:last-child {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: none;
}

/* heading styling */
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4aaaa5;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4aaaa5;
    padding: 25px 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
}
```